# Typo3 8.7 extend core form extension

Tags: forms, class, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I would like to extend a controller from the typo3 form extension.

Thats my code in the ext_localconf from my own customer extension

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Form\\Domain\\Model\\Renderable\\AbstractCompositeRenderable'] = array(
    'className' => 'Staempfli\TemplateBootstrap\Model\Renderable\Statusbar'
);
```

There is no error thrown but my class Statusbar is not noticed from typo3.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The XCLASS model of TYPO3 does not recognize your change, because you want to replace an Abstract class, that gets extended only and never instanciated. You can only XCLASS classes, that can get instanciated by GeneralUtility::makeInstance. The abstract class however will get extended like so:
`SomeClass extends AbstractClass`
This way, TYPO3 has no way of changing the extends, because it is a PHP keyword and PHP takes care of searching the class. TYPO3 can not change a thing on this behavior.

Comment: Is there another possibility than to override the class?